# how can i add this to my html page with jquery html()?

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying something like when i click something some html code generate for eg.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#state2").click(function(){


    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val=="TASSUB"){


        $(".text").html("

        <div class="add_info">
<p><strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel </p>
<p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;"> 5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000 </P>
<p><strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Monday 15 September</p>
<p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p>
 <p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;">(2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)
</P>

</div>

        ");

        }

    else if(val=="SASUB"){


        $(".text").html("<p>SA-Tuesday 16 September 3.00 – 5.00pm</P>");

        }

    });


</script>
```

when i click on a select menu of #state2 it should create some html code . but it shows erro. what should i do?

Comment: your string literal is not proper...

Comment: use append function instead of html - http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: problem is $(".text").html(...... Not properly formatted string;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("#state2").click(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val=="TASSUB"){
                $(".text").html('<div class="add_info"><p><strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel </p><p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;"> 5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000 </P><p><strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Monday 15 September</p><p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p><p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;">(2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)</p></div>');
            }
            else if(val=="SASUB"){
                $(".text").html("<p>SA-Tuesday 16 September 3.00 – 5.00pm</P>");
            }
        });
```

I've changed the quotes because there are many double quotes in the string, when we copy the html and paste in the script for this kind of requirement you need to ensure there are no quotes (double or single) which conflict with the string you're adding.

There is another solution also available, in the string replace double quotes into single quotes, problem solved!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0sg4125x/2/)**

Comment: I would add that the REASON this works is because you've changed the quotes from double to single so the string is properly formatted - otherwise it doesn't really help future visitors.

Comment: Yes i changed the quotes alone, why because there are many double quotes in the string, always we copy the html and paste it in the script for this kind of req. , most of people do not concentrate in quotes! for that only i did like this :)  there is another solution also available, in the string replace double quotes into single quotes :) problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Missing `"$"` sign before this ( ".text " ).html( " ... ") and `content inside .html function is not quoted properly`.
Try this:

```
 $("#state2").click(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val=="TASSUB")
            {
               $(".text").html('<div class="add_info"><p><strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel </p><p style=" text-indent: 3.5em;"> 5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000 </P><p><strong>Date: </strong>&nbsp; Monday 15 September</p><p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p><p style="text-indent: 3.5em;">(2.30pm arrival for registration</p></div>');
            }
            else if(val=="SASUB"){
                $("#state1").html("<p>SA-Tuesday 16 September 3.00 – 5.00pm</P>");
            }
        });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oa9e3bou/1/)
Also, `you are using "text" as class name` in HTML which is `not good practice` because text is the standard input type name in HTML. `<input type="text" />`

Comment: Is it okay if there was a white spaces inside `.html` e.g. `enter`?

Comment: I think this would not work because I just copied your code and  test in fiddle .. It did not work.. Can you provide a fiddle. I am just puzzled because whenever I add white spaces inside `.html` it causes an error..

Comment: @HTTP Made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oa9e3bou/). Kindly have a look at it.Seems working fine :)

Comment: What I mean in white spaces is that if you format your code just like your answer (You have line breaks e.g. if you hit enter). Try to paste your code in fiddle and see it it will work. Thats the time you will get what I mean on whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sg4125x/)

Your code inside `.html` is not properly quoted and I do not know if I an correct but base from my experience using `.html` in creating elements in jquery will not work with white spaces

```
$(".text").html("<div class='add_info'><p><strong>Venue:</strong> Henry Jones Art Hotel </p><p style=' text-indent: 3.5em;'> 5 Hunter St, Hobart TAS 7000 </P><p><strong>Time: </strong>&nbsp; 3.00 – 5.00pm</p><p style=' text-indent: 3.5em;'>(2.30pm arrival for registration and refreshments)</P></div>");
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try id by class name selector `$(".text").Html("Your Html Content ")`.

Comment: What $(".text") is not proper way? Dont you know how to use class selector?

Comment: please reconsider your answer.. thanpa eruku sakthi... both .class and #id is correctu than ... sekiram change pannu pa..